# Running an exe in PowerShell script

Tags: powershell

I have a PowerShell script that downloads an exe and then runs it.

The download part of the code works fine but the issue is when the script goes to run the exe.

`Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://...redacted..." -OutFile "C:\application.exe"`

I'm using `Start-Process -Wait -FilePath "C:\application.exe" -ArgumentList "/conf conf.xml`

The error that I get is
*Suggestion [3,General]: The command application.exe was not found, but does exist in the current location. Windows PowerShell does not load commands from the current location by default. If you trust this command, instead type: ".\application.exe". See "get-help about_Command_Precedence" for more details.*

I found this [post](https://superuser.com/questions/1373012/avoid-dot-backslash-windows-10-powershell) on the topic but how would I implement it in my line of code?

If I'm in PowerShell and run `.\application.exe /conf conf.xml` it runs with no errors. I just get the errors when I run the .ps1 script.

Comment: Some code appears to be missing from your post - where's the part that downloads the file to `C:\application.exe`?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen added.

Comment: Try creating a directory (eg `New-item -ItemType Directory -Path c:\temp`) and download/run your app from there instead of the root directory. Adjust the paths after `-OutFile` and `-FilePath` accordingly. Does the app start if you remove `-NoNewWindow`?

Comment: @MisterSmith I created a directory and the files download fine. I removed ```-NoNewWindow``` and the application kicks off but then I get an error. In my original post I forgot to add the argument. ```Start-Process -FilePath "C:\folder\application.exe" -ArgumentList "/conf conf.xml"```

Comment: Either use an absolute path to your config file, or add `-WorkingDirectory c:\folder` to your `Start-Process` (assuming conf.xml is located in `c:\folder`)

Comment: @MisterSmith thank you. Adding ```-WorkingDirectory "C:\folder"``` fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

@MisterSmith thank you that resolved the issue.

`Start-Process -WorkingDirectory "C:\folder" -Wait -FilePath "C:\folder\application.exe" - ArgumentList "/conf conf.xml"`